# Change text opacity when hovering a image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

Hi I want to change the text opacity when hovering a image. I tried to use this but it doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>

<img src="image1.jpg" class="first-image">
```

CSS:

```
.text {
opacity: 0;
}

.first-image:hover {
text.opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason preventing you from changing the HTML markup? You'll need to change the markup to do this with only CSS.

Comment: @hopkins-matt What changes should I do?( I can use JavaScript or whatever, not only CSS).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the way you was doing it with pure CSS, revised snippet below:

```
<dic class="first-image">
 <img src="image1.jpg" alt="first-image"/>
 <div class="text">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

..

```
.text {
   opacity: 0;
  }

  .first-image:hover > div{
     opacity: 1;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, grab the class of the image, and on `hover`, change the `opacity` of the `text` class to 1.

```
 $('.first-image').hover(function(){
  $('.text').css('opacity', '1');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery to listen for a mouseenter event on the image. When that event is fired, add a class (like `active`) to the `<div class="text">` element so it would look like `<div class="text active">`. On the exit of the mousenter event (mouseleave), make sure to remove the `active` class. OR you can modify the css through jQuery directly.
2. Add css to change the text opacity: 
   `.text.active {
     opacity: 0.5;
   }`